# Handling unexpected mutations properties in Vue3js

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

I have a vue3 webapp that I use to edit some multi-pages documents.
All the pages are stored in a state with pinia. My pinia state is an object with a `pages` property that is an array containing all the data of each page.

Each page of each document use a specific template, so I created multiple components to handle each template, and I also have subcomponents for some parts that can be found across multiple templates.
I loop through the pages with a root component, passing a reference to the page object, like it :
`<PageWrapper v-for="page in pages" :key="page.id" :page="page" />`

Then, inside the PageWrapper component, I use the according page template's component, passing along a reference to the page object (the same with subcomponents if any) :

```
<PageFirst v-if="props.page.type === 'first'" :page="props.page" />
<PageServices v-if="props.page.type === 'services'" :page="props.page" />
<PageTotal v-if="props.page.type === 'total'" :page="props.page" />
<PageContent v-if="props.page.type === 'content'" :page="props.page" />
```

I wonder what would be the best way to edit a property of my `page` object from a subcomponent, as I know that it is a bad practice to mutate the property directly.
Do I have to use events ? Is `PageWrapper` the good place to catch all the events and the modifications?

Any advice on this matter would be of great help to me.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That was one big difference between Pinia and Vuex, that with Vuex, state mutations should only be done within the Vuex store, while Pinia encourages mutations of state anywhere. I think that one reason for this change is that  devtools can now track mutations even though they are not performed within the store. So, *perhaps* it is "more" OK now to perform state mutations within subcomponents, but having said this, note that I am not a Vue or Pinia expert, just an interested learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Vue official document](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow) point out:

> In most cases, the child should emit an event to let the parent perform the mutation.

So the answer is you should let the parent do the job of mutating the props. And it will **never be a bad solution.**

But, look at your design. Your parent component `PageWrapper` works just like a wrapper. It does nothing but a container for its child.

The props [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow) prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent's state, which can make your app's data flow harder to understand. But if the parent does not actually handle state and your child component's data does not relate with each other, mutating the props inside the child component will be **fine**.